# Android - Add existing app to another app as a library project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I have generally followed the steps to convert my app into a library project by updating the `build.gradle` to have `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and then including it my other app by adding it to the `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`.

I can see that the library project compiles when I go a gradle sync on the app to which I have added the library. However I am unable to invoke or access code from the library from within the app. What's the right way to do this?

The library project is an app that has a `MainActivity` and generally behaves like any Android app. Is there anything else that needs to be done to make it into a proper library project?

Exception while launching Activity from library from app that includes the library:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{myapp.debug/mylib.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "mylib.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.debug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "mylib.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.debug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                              at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                             Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.janacare.aina.MainActivity
>                                                                              at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                     ... 13 more
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack available

Comment: Give an example of code you want to call. Is it an activity you want to start? Is it a static method in a class?

Comment: It is an activity. Launched via an intent. I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to do that.

Comment: Show your app's manifest.xml, and the code you use to launch the activity from your lib and the full error message you get

Comment: Did you add your library as a dependency in your app? Can you show your other app build.gradle?

Comment: I have added `compile project(':mylibraryproject')` to the `dependencies` section of my `build.gradle` and I have added `include ':mylibraryproject'`
project(':mylibraryproject').projectDir = new File('mylibraryproject/ProjectName')` to the app's `settings.gradle`.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing all the right things. Double check that you added the `compile...` line to the correct build.gradle in the correct dependencies section (there are multiple). Also open the dependency jar/aar  with a zip utility like 7-zip and ensure that MainActivity is available in it in the correct namespace.

Comment: Please add your code for build.gradle, your app's main activity and your library's main activity. These are the essential pieces of info that will help us decode the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try these

in android studio, click file->new->import module->browse to your library will be app location
this method will automatically add your app to gradle and import your app to your project

Answer (score 0):

Implement this code for launch library module Activity in another android project

1) Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

2) i.setComponent(new ComponentName("myparent.company.com.myparent", 
   "myparent.company.com.myparent.MainActivity"));

3)startActivity(i);

but Gives me Error :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mychild.agamitech.com.mychild/mychild.agamitech.com.mychild.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {myparent.company.com.myparent/myparent.company.com.myparent.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I want use My Another Project activity into Many other projects